# Beautiful Soup will not return anything legible

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape multiple webpages that are supposed to be identical in layout. Some of them scrape fine, but others return empty lists. printing the page content returns various forms of gibberish.

Initial set up code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import soupsieve

addresses = ["https://aWebsite.asp?id=1234"]

for a in range(0,len(addresses)):
    url = addresses[a]

    page = requests.get(url)
```

But from here I get various forms of gibberish no matter which encoding or features I use.

**When I try:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content) #or soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
cells = soup.select("tr p")
    print(soup)
    print(cells)
```

It prints:

```
<html><body><p>‹      ¼XñOÜ¸þ™JïüTR½Y8½+…Mž(P•{TÔëUò&amp;</p></body></html>

[]
```

**When I try:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='html.parser')

cells = soup.select("tr p")
print(soup)
print(cells)
```

It prints: (I shorted the soup print as it was long, but that is a sample)

```
5���������/�b뱻��־E�g;�jw��&amp;����Ͻ��a��`~�?]5-�
�����[+�j</em"�p��></m.ﻟ�s)1�3�s�c{uoũⶰ�v^goh�m���;h�></f�g���*></n�`�<7`�ly��x�#tb></ii�����t�>

[]
```

**When I try:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content).get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")

cells = soup.select("tr p")
print(soup)
print(cells)
```

It prints:

```
b'\xe2\x80\xb9      \xc2\xbc=\xc3\x9br\xc2\xb9r\xc3\x8fR\xc3\x95\xc3\xbe'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "warn_scrape.py", line 45, in <module>
    cells = soup.select("tr p")
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'select'
```

**When I try:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

    cells = soup.select("tr p").get_text()
    print(soup)
    print(cells)
```

It prints:

```
<html><body><p>‹      ¼</p></body></html>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "warn_scrape.py", line 45, in <module>
    cells = soup.select("tr p").get_text()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I've tried many other ways and combinations of the above including `.prettify`, and `encode("ascii")' and they all return empty lists and some form of gibberish html

Comment: I think it's worth seeing how the source code of `"https://aWebsite.asp?id=1234"` looks like, can you provide it in the question?

Comment: Is there anything in the source code I should zero in on? Don't want to post page for privacy.

Comment: if it's private, don't, but are you sure if every pages are identical? the fact that some can be parsed and some cannot with the same parsing algorithm is strange

Comment: Have you checked if it's requests library returning the gibberish, or does BeautifulSoup transfrom the readable response content to gibberish? Also what is the response value for content-type header: `page.headers.get('content-type')`?

Comment: The pages appear identical. Some have leading white space in <p> tags and `&nbsp;` but that is all I see. 

When I print the `page.content` I get a long odd unicode such as `\x90[+\xdfj\x00\x00'`. `page.headers.get()` returns `text/html`

Comment: Hm. so it says `text/html`. I see no reason why this shouldn't work with python requests if it works with a web browser. You might be missing some headers to pass along with your request. Try intercepting the request you web browser makes (with a tool such as mitmproxy) to see what all headers are being sent, and see if you can replicate them with your python code. I doubt anyone would be able to tell what exactly is wrong here since we can't access the website.